# x86 Why does C function disassembly show different value for pointer when pushed to call stack

Tags: c, assembly, x86, gdb, disassembly

gdt.h:

```
void gdt_load(struct segment_descriptor_raw *gdt, uint16_t size);
```

gdt.c:

```
struct segment_descriptor_raw gdt_raw[TOTAL_GDT_SEGMENTS];
gdt_load(gdt_raw, sizeof(gdt_raw));
```

When I open GDB to step through this code, I get the address of the `gdb_raw` array by executing `print &gdt_raw[0]` and I get an output of `0x380`. I confirmed that this is the actual address of the array, and not the address of the pointer to the array, by examining the memory at 0x380 with the x command in gdb.

gdt.asm:

```
gdt_load:
    mov eax, [esp + 4]              
    mov [gdt_descriptor + 2], eax   
    mov ax, [esp + 8]               
    mov [gdt_descriptor], ax        
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]           
    ret
```

Now, as I step through the above assembly code in GDB, I expect the value at [esp + 4], the first argument to the function, to be the address of `gdt_raw` (`0x380`).  However, it's not.  It's the value 0x106000. Curious as to why this is the case, I stepped into the assembly directly after calling gdt_load: via `layout asm` and `stepi` and this is what I see:

```
push 0x18
push 0x106000
call 0x10806e
```

These are the arguments getting passed to the function. 0x18 makes sense, this is the size of the gdt and what I expect.  However, why is the other argument 0x106000 and not 0x380?

Does this have something to do with 0x380 being the address of `gdt_raw` in the symbol table, but once the file is mapped to memory, the address we're seeing in the assembly code is the real address of gdt_raw in memory?  This is my guess but I'm hoping someone can confirm or deny.

And, if the above is true, then when I use the x command in GDB to view the bytes at a memory location, are those bytes not the real memory, but instead only the offset within the object file?

Update: [Makefile](https://github.com/RyanStan/ConiferOS/blob/64921e13e12b3a6a68ada91a7e7405e2b8b935bd/Makefile) and [linker script](https://github.com/RyanStan/ConiferOS/blob/64921e13e12b3a6a68ada91a7e7405e2b8b935bd/src/linker.ld)

Comment: Not that it's your primary issue, but the limit value for the GDT should be the size of the GDT minus 1.

Comment: What linker script do you use? Can you dump map file (`-Map=%` option for `ld`)?

Comment: It might be a position independent executable. If you load that into gdb you will get 0-based addresses (offsets) until you run it.

Comment: It appears this is your OS on Github? https://github.com/RyanStan/ConiferOS/blob/master/Makefile

Comment: Completely unrelated t your questions, if you are on Linux you might consider installing `mtools` to handle vfat/fat disk images, copy files to a disk image etc. Those tools allow you to do that without root privileges.

Comment: @Jester You're right, I compiled it with --relocatable.  Does that mean that GDB, even once I'm executing the application, still only sees the 0-based addresses when I print the addresses?

Comment: Looking at your code you link relocatable to an object file and use that for symbols, then you link that to a binary which is at a fixed place in memory (at 0x100000). It is unclear what you are doing. You add the symbols from an unlinked object for debugging which might be the issue (everything will be relative to 0). What happens if you use this makefile https://pastebin.com/5rNN3jyP . It generales `kernel.elf` with symbols and then I use `objcopy` to generate a binary `kerne.bin` from that.

Comment: For the above Makefile to work you need to modify linker.ld so the `OUTPUT(binary)` is chaned to `OUTPUT(elf32-i386)`.  You can then use `kernel.elf` for symbols rather than `kernelfull.o` when debugging.

Comment: Oops I wrote `kerne.bin` in the comment above when it should have been `kernel.bin`

Comment: To truly get relocatable code to work you'd have to build a relocatable ELF executable then your code that loads the kernel into memory would have to have something that loads (parses ELF)  an elf executable into memory and loads it into memory at the required memory addresses. Your code just loads raw binary (`kernel.bin`) thus it isn't relocatable.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank you for that example!  I learned a lot from examining your kernel.elf file's symbol tables vs the relocatable kernelfull.o file. I can see from objdump on the kernel.elf file that it has the address of gdt_raw as 00106000, which is the value I saw when I stepped through the assembly instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I was pulling debug symbols from the symbol table of a relocatable object file.

I was generating a relocatable object file, `build/kernelfull.o`.  Then, I converted this file into a binary that was loaded into memory at `0x100000`.  In GDB, when executing the binary, I pulled in the symbol table from the relocatable file with `add-symbol-file build/kernelfull.o 0x100000`.

Thus, GDB only knew an address for `gdt_raw` that was relative to `0`. To correct this, I had to create an ELF Executable (as opposed to ELF Relocatable) which I then converted into a binary (`objcopy`).  By using the debugging symbols of this ELF Executable, GDB could see that `gdt_raw` was indeed at the address `0x106000`

Thanks to @MichaelPetch for figuring this out.